# How to add two horizontal frame to the main window using RGtk2 in r?

Tags: r, user-interface, gtk, gtk2

I'm using `RGtk2` package to create a GUI for my data analysis in `R`. The following code is written in `R` to create main window as well as vertical box in a frame named "Prediction".

```
    library(RGtk2)
    #main window
    main_window <- gtkWindow("toplevel",show=F)
    main_window["title"] <- "My App"

    #Frame
    frame <- gtkFrameNew("Prediction")
    frame$setLabelAlign(xalign=10, yalign=10)
    main_window$add(frame)

    #V Box
    vbox <- gtkVBoxNew(show=T, spacing=10)
    vbox$setBorderWidth(30)
    frame$add(vbox)

    #H Box
    hbox <- gtkHBoxNew(show=T, spacing=10)
    vbox$packStart(child=hbox, expand=F, fill=F, padding=0)
```

What I want is to have two horizontal different parts in the main window, first to predict the result and second to plot some curves. I don't know how to do it in R. As far as I've tested, we can't have 2 frames in one window. What other objects can I choose? Is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: You're already using the object to use: a V Box to stack two things on top of one another, or an H Box to put things on opposite sides. There's also a Paned, which gives you two halves that can be resized by dragging a bar in the middle.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/unstable/GtkPaned.html (it's also in GTK+ 3 if you ever do find a way to use that instead)